# Parameter Substitution

Tags: linux

I want to know the difference between the following two options for parameter substitution in Linux.

```
echo ${MESG:? "HI"}
echo ${MESG:- "HI"}
```

They both seem to do the same thing.

Comment: What are you doing that causes you to think they both do the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

From the `bash` manual ([the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) has a similar wording):

> `${parameter:-word}`: *Use Default Values*.  If `parameter` is unset or null, the
>          expansion of `word` is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of
>          `parameter` is substituted.
>
> `${parameter:?word}`: *Display Error if Null or Unset*.  If `parameter` is null or unset,
>   the expansion of `word` (or a message to that effect if `word` is
>   not present) is written to the standard error and the shell, if
>   it is not interactive, exits.  Otherwise, the value of `parameter`
>   is substituted.

If your `MESG` variable is a non-null string of characters, they would do the same thing (expand to the value of the `MESG` variable). If it's empty or not set at all, then `${MESG:-HI}` would be replaced by the string `HI`, and `${MESG:?HI}` would display `HI` on standard error and exit the current shell session (unless it's an interactive session).

Answer (score -1):

If MESG is not set then

```
echo ${MESG:?}
```

would print

```
MESG: parameter null or not set


echo ${MESG:-}
```

would print

```
<empty string>
```

The ? and - therefore dictates how null or not set variables are dealt with